# Запрос для выбора фиксированного n-го количества записей из таблицы

Tags: mysql, sql

Для примера дана таблица `country_ranks`
со следующей структурой:

```
   id    | country_id    |   rank
-- 150 --| -- 245399 --  |  -- 1 --
-- 151 --| -- 2324254 -- |  -- 2 --
-- 152 --| -- 345434 --  |  -- 3 --
-- 153 --| -- 3453235 -- |  -- 4 --
-- 154 --| -- 54531 --   |  -- 5 --
-- 155 --| -- 64693 --   |  -- 6 --
-- 156 --| -- 59610 --   |  -- 7 --
-- 157 --| -- 29945 --   |  -- 8 --
-- 158 --| -- 105539 --  |  -- 9 --
```

Нужно получить 5 записей, с условием где country_id = ?

Могут быть следующие случаи:

- если запись в таблице первая (к примеру country_id = 245399),то берем ее и следующие 4
- если запись последняя то ее и 4 предыдущих.
- если запись по средине (к примеру country_id = 345434),то эту запись, 2 предыдущие и 2 следующие после нее.
- запись на втором месте (country_id = 2324254), берем 1 сзади,текущую и 3 следующих.

**Update:** первой записью в таблице является,та перед которой больше нет других записей, min(id).
Последняя запись та после которой больше нет других записей,т.е max(id).
`country_id` - уникальное поле! Сортировка по полю rank.
Хотелось бы универсально без привязки к бд,но решение для MySQL подойдет!

Comment: Определитесь с БД. Все таки MySQL или PostgreSQL? Что значит `первая`, `последняя`? По какому критерию сортируем? `country_id` уникальное поле или нет?

Comment: Добавил уточнения.

Comment: `первой записью в таблице является...min(id)` `Сортировка по полю rank` эти две фразы противоречат друг другу

Answer (score 0):

```
-- set @num = country_id целевой записи
select *
from test 
where rank >= ( select max(q2.rank) 
                from ( select rank
                       from test
                       where rank <= ( select min(q1.rank) 
                                       from ( select rank
                                              from test
                                              where country_id <= @num
                                              order by rank desc
                                              limit 3
                                            ) q1
                                     )
                       order by rank asc
                       limit 5
                     ) q2
              )
order by rank asc
limit 5;
```